# Asked for my boss a raise, but never received feedback

Tags: management, internship, raise, conversation

I'm currently working as a trainee in a software development company. In this company there are two programs for trainees: one that pays for 20 hours/week and other that pays for 30 hours/week (obviously, the more you work, the more you receive). Currently I am working 20 hours/week and asked for my boss to migrate my contract to the 30 hours/week plan. He said that he would talk with his associate.

This happened last month and he still has not followed up. I want to ask to him if he talked with his partner, but I don't really know how to do this without being annoying/awkward, especially as I'm effectively asking for a pay raise/more permanent job with the company. How can I phrase my request? Should it be via email, in person, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not awkward. As Joe said, just walk up to him and ask. *Hey boss, have you had a chance to [blah blah blah]*?

Never be afraid to look after yourself and be assertive about it. If you don't, no one will.